# Is it guaranteed that (float [m*n]) equals (std::array<std::array<float,m>,n>) in C++ 11

Tags: arrays, c++11

When I use [this lib](https://github.com/recastnavigation/recastnavigation), they declare & usage an Array of Vector3 like this (not exactly like, but ideally like)

```
#define DIMENSION 3
#define ARRAY_LEN 7

/*Declare*/
float Raw[DIMENSION*ARRAY_LEN] = { 0 };

/*Usage*/
for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_LEN;i+=3)
{
    (&Raw[i])[0] = 1.0f;
    (&Raw[i])[1] = 2.0f;
    (&Raw[i])[2] = 3.0f;
}
```

I find this very hard to maintain and scale.

I hear that std::vector elements are guaranteed to be contiguous, so I want to make it a 2 dimension array using the std::array

```
array<array<float,DIMENSION>,ARRAY_LEN> arr;
```

Through my test, I found out that this could be true. Even though I know that std::vector can't, but I test for std::vector anyway

```
float Raw[DIMENSION*ARRAY_LEN] = { 0 };
vector<vector<float>> vec;
vec.resize(ARRAY_LEN);
for (vector<float> &v : vec)
{
    v.resize(DIMENSION);
}
array<array<float,DIMENSION>,ARRAY_LEN> arr;

int i;
i = 0;
for (int n = DIMENSION*ARRAY_LEN, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    Raw[i] = i;
}

i = 0;
for (vector<float> &item : vec)
{
    for (float &f : item)
    {
        f = i++;
    }
}
i = 0;
for (array<float, DIMENSION> &item : arr)
{
    for (float &f : item)
    {
        f = i++;
    }
}

float* testVec;
testVec = &vec[0][0];

float* testArr;
testArr = &arr[0][0];

for (int n = DIMENSION*ARRAY_LEN, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (testVec[i] != Raw[i])
    {
        printf("Test vec %d\n", i);
    }
    if (testArr[i] != Raw[i])
    {
        printf("Test arr %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

So I test it though, but still I wonder if it's safe. I want to confirm if it guaranteed that (`float [m*n]`) equals (`std::array<std::array<float,m>,n>`)

**Edit:** If the answer is not guaranteed that this is true, it is prefered to point out a circumstance that it would be wrong.

Comment: *I want to confirm if it guaranteed that `(float [m*n])` equals `(std::array<std::array<float,m>,n>)`* What sort of guarantee are you looking for?

Comment: I don't believe there's a guarantee that `std::array<T, N>` doesn't contain any members besides `N` copies of `T`, and is exactly `N*sizeof(T)` in size; and you need this guarantee for `std::array`-of-`std::arrays` to have the same contiguous storage as a plain C 2D array. Now, this property likely holds for most implementations, so chances are high you would get away with it. But  relying on this would technically make your code non-portable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Actually, there is a guarantee that `array` doesn't contain more members. It is an aggregate, and must therefore be able to undergo aggregate initialization like a regular array. If it had members before the array subobject, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @NicolBolas But it could have members after, couldn't it? E.g. MSVC has iterator debugging mode, whereby `std::vector` keeps track of every outstanding iterator on it, to flag use-after-invalidation. I can imagine an implementation of `std::array` doing something similar.

Comment: padding is also implementation defined, you could have `sizeof(array<char, 3>) == 4` for example

Comment: @NicolBolas And in any case, extra members aside, I don't think it's guaranteed that, for `struct S { int m[42]; }`, it must be true that `sizeof(S) == sizeof(int[42])`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I never said that was guaranteed. I was only talking about the "extra members" stuff.

Comment: But as I test, I do see that sizeof(arr) == sizeof(Raw) == 84. So is it a coincidence in MSVC compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `array` and `vector` are required to be contiguous. However, the ability to jump from one ***sub***-element of an `array`/`vector` element to a sub-element of another `array`/`vector` element is *not* guaranteed.

That is, you cannot jump from `arr[0][3]` to `arr[1][0]` just by incrementing a `float*`. Even ignoring strict standard wording for pointer arithmetic, an `array<T, N>` is allowed to have padding, so `sizeof(array<T, N>)` is not required to be `sizeof(T[N])`. Multidimensional `vector`s are even more problematic, as each element `vector` has its own allocation, which will certainly not be contiguous with other allocations.

> If the answer is not guaranteed that this is true, it is prefered to point out a circumstance that it would be wrong.

It's *always* wrong. Multiple `vector` elements of a `vector<vector<T>>` will have different allocations. Period.

As for `array`, C++ does not allow pointer arithmetic across arrays, only *within* an array. And if you want to ignore that (you will neither be the first nor the last), it will still fail any time `sizeof(array<T, N>) != sizeof(T[N])`. And that cannot be known a priori; it is an implementation detail and will vary from compiler to compiler, from `T` to `T`, and from `N` to `N`.

Comment: uhm,... I see, but currently, is there a circumstance that it (the statement in this question) would be wrong?

Comment: @123iamking: All of them. All circumstances.

Comment: But If I have function like this: ReadAndWriteArray(float* arr, int arrayLen), then if I pass &arr[0][0] and ARRAY_LEN (prefer the code in the question), it still work correctly, right? the function ReadAndWriteArray assumes that the array is float Raw[DIMENSION*ARRAY_LEN].

Comment: @123iamking: I'm not sure what part of "not guaranteed" is unclear.

Comment: "not guaranteed" I mean: not safe. Edit: oh, I see, so it is not safe.